# External Disk shows used up space but i am not able to find any files inside

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, macbook-pro, macos-mojave, file-search

I have a MacBook Pro with Mac OS 10.14.6.

My external hard disk was working fine until one day all of a sudden it went blank, it doesn't show files anymore...

I have a WD external HD and I am using unlocker service given by WD to unlock by HD, that works always but after that the HD shows up in Volumes, then if I get inside that, I don't see any files.

The HD format is NTFS and I tried to create a new folder inside the HD; whenever I create a new folder it is getting created and then vanishes away, and when I try to create next new folder the naming sequence continues.

First aid option is disabled in Disk utility.

Tried leaving the HD in the Mac for more than a day... still nothing showed up.

Please help!

Comment: You do have a backup of those important files, don't you.

Comment: no i dont...i was using this HD as my backup Drive

Comment: macOS doesn't natively support NTFS. There are several ways to add NTFS support, but I'd bet there's a bug in whatever you're using. I would strongly recommend *not* using NTFS with macOS; if you need Windows compatibility, ExFAT is a much better option; if not, use Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format.

Comment: I understand that MacOS doesn't support NTFS and to overcome that i did something long back(that i dont remember now) and due to that i was using this without any issue,once i unlock the drive the HD wont show up in the left bar i have to always navigate to "Volumes" in order to view and operate it and it was fine till the day issue showed up

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unlocking your drive then opening terminal and typing `ls -la /Volumes/{my-drive-name}/{filepath-to-missing-files}`? This will show you all the hidden files in the directory the filepath leads to.

I have had a problem before where Finder was automatically hiding some of the files in my drive for some reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response,i tried this using terminal but i am getting some input/output error when trying to enter the path using terminal ...for the command s -la /Volumes/{my-drive-name} -> i am not getting any error but once i put this : ls -la /Volumes/{my-drive-name}/{filepath-to-missing-files} i get an Input/Output error